# How to create a rdp file with clear password?

Tags: file, web, passwords, rdp

I'm trying to generate a .rdp filein my web application to send my webclients with the correct mime type. Then, they open the file with a rdp client app and make a automatic connection to a machine.

After reading this article

http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/18/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted/

It seems that it not possible to create a rdp file in a machine and use it in other machine without decrypt and encrypt again the password in the client.

I'm looking a directive in the rdp file to write the password in clear to avoid this problem, like:

```
password:s:Passw0rd
```

Regards

Raul